# Пустое письмо с формы обратной связи

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть простая форма обратной связи.

```
  <form action="./mail.php" method="POST">
         <input type="text" name="name" required="" placeholder="Введите имя">
         <input type="tel" name="phone" required="" placeholder="Введите телефон">
         <button type="submit" class="button inverse" href="#orderForm">Хочу узнать</button>      
         <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="utm_placement" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="utm_creative" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="">         
    </form>
```

Содержимое mail.php

```
<?php
$to1      =  'mail@mail.com';
$subject = 'Заявка c сайтa '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$message = 'На сайт '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].' поступила новая заявка.<br>';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$var){
    if(!empty($var)) $message .= $key .' : '. $var .'<br>';
}
$message .= '<br>Письмо отправлено автоматически и не требует ответа';
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: ROBOT <robot@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
mail($to1, $subject, $message, $headers);
mail($to2, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Код js

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "../mail.php", data: $(this).serialize() }).done(function() {
        $(this).find("input").val("");
        $("form").trigger("reset");
    });
    $.arcticmodal('close');   
    event.preventDefault();
});
return false;
```

С форм обычно приходит вся нужная информация. Но временами, по непонятной причине, приходят странные пустые письма, содержащие только "На сайт поступила новая заявка. Письмо отправлено автоматически и не требует ответа" и больше ничего. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Нашел причину. Если в браузере в меню разработчика удалить весь HTML код до кнопки отправить, то происходит отсылка пустого письма. Понять бы теперь как избавиться от этой оказии.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в обработчике - не проверяете заполненность полей. Вот и шлют пустую форму. Даже если используете проверку на клиенте, то никогда нельзя этой проверке доверять - всегда проверять еще раз на сервере.

Comment: Тогда должны приходить пустые поля, даже не заполненные

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на свой код. Если значение пришло пустое - в письмо ничего не добавится.

Comment: Выше я написал причину.

Comment: Это не причина. У вас на сервере данные не проверяются по сути своей. Вот причина.

Answer (score 0):

Обработчик должен быть примерно такой:

```
    <?php
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $mytel = $_POST['phone'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $captcha_code = $_POST['captcha_code'];
  $error = '';
  if(!$name) {$error .= 'Укажите свое имя. ';}
  if(!$email) {$error .= 'Укажите электронную почту. ';}
  if($captcha_code != 12) {$error .= 'Код проверки введен некорректно, либо пуст. ';}
  if(!$message || strlen($message) < 1) {$error .= 'Введите сообщение. ';}
  if(!$error) {
    $address = "xxx@mail.ru"; //почта на которую будут приходить письма
    $sub = "Тема сообщения здесь";
    $mes = "Имя: ".$name."\n\nE-mail: ".$email."\n\nТелефон: ".$mytel."\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\n";
    $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
    if($send) {echo 'OK';}
  }
  else {echo '<div class="err">'.$error.'</div>';}
}
?>
```

Comment: Обработчик срабатывает отлично. Проблема не в нем точно.